# "Лицо(,) старше 60 лет"

Tags: пунктуация

"Лицо(,) старше 60 лет" — нужна ли указанная запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, "старше 60 лет" - несогласованное определение. Но для точного ответа необходим контекст, хотя бы предложение, а не обрывок. Если же речь о словосочетании "лицо старше 60 лет", то, само собой, никаких запятых не требуется.

Comment: А если это коплимент? "У тебя лицо - старше 60 лет"?
Даже гадать без контекста не хочется.